# Maintain counter of a global variable across function

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

I have a counter which is local to the scope of a parent function and being passed across multiple child functions and is incremented across multiple instances. I am having trouble maintaining the count

I have tried the following

```
var maxLimit = 150;
async function incrementCounter(counter) {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
  return counter;
}

async function processRights() {
  var counter = 0,
    end = false;
  var queryInput = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < queryInput.length; i++) {
    var element = queryInput[i];
    var thOutput = await processTitle(counter, element, 'th');
    if (!thOutput) {
      end = true;
      return;
    }
    var nthOutput = await processTitle(counter, element, 'nth');
    if (!nthOutput) {
      end = true;
      return;
    };
  }
  if (!queryInput || !queryInput.length) {
    end = true;
  }
  return;
}

async function processTitle(counter, element, type) {
  var output = await callFunc(counter, element, type);
  if (!output) {
    return false;
  }
  return output;
}

async function callFunc(counter, element) {
  var responses = [];
  var counterValue1 = await incrementCounter(counter);
  if (counterValue1 >= maxLimit) {
    return false;
  }
  await callAnotherFunc();
  if (1) {
    var qryArr = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1];
    for (let i = 0; i < qryArr.length; i++) {
      var counterValue2 = await incrementCounter(counterValue1);
      console.log("counterValue2 -- " + counterValue2);
      if (counterValue2 >= maxLimit) {
        return false;
      }
      await callAnotherFunc();
    }
    return responses;
  }
}

async callAnotherFunc(){
    return true;
}
processRights();
```

I would like the increment the counter and check against the maximum limit each time the callAnotherFunc function is called. I am a novice to JS. Pl help!

Answer (score 1):

If the counter can be really a global variable, you can declare it side by side with the maxLimit variable, something like this:

```
var overallCounter = 0;
var maxLimit = 150;

...

async callAnotherFunc(){
    return overallCounter++ <= maxLimit;
}
```

From the question and the code I think this is what you want to achieve, right?

Comment: Not really. My problem here is that I am unable to maintain the incremental counter when its being passed down across multiple functions. And the counter cant be a global variable. It can be declared within the scope of the parent function and be passed down

Comment: "callAnotherFunc" must be accessed even by other code/modules? If not, we can declare it inside "callFunc" to capture the "counter" variable and just use it. This way the variable is not global and "callAnotherFunc" can access the updated counter.